# How to detect click outside of my popup window?

Tags: android, xamarin

Hey I want to detect a click outside of popup window here is my code

```
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
    builder.SetTitle(Resource.String.rating_dialog_title);
    builder.SetMessage(Resource.String.rating_dialog_desc);
    builder.SetNegativeButton(Resource.String.yes, (s, e) =>
    {
        SetAppRateStatus(AppRateStausEnum.RateNow);
        IMvxWebBrowserTask help = new MvxWebBrowserTask();
        help.ShowWebPage("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details");
    });

    builder.SetNeutralButton(Resource.String.no, (s, e) =>
    {
        SetAppRateStatus(AppRateStausEnum.RemindMeLater);
    });

    builder.SetPositiveButton(Resource.String.never, (s, e) =>
    {
        SetAppRateStatus(AppRateStausEnum.Never);
    });
```

So please suggest me code that detects a click outside of popup window,
Thank you

Comment: You can use  setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false/true);

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying about

```
builder.SetCancelable();
```

check this link

[Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder.SetCancelable Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.AlertDialog+Builder.SetCancelable/p/System.Boolean/)

or

```
builder.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside ()
```

check this link below

[Android.App.Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside/p/System.Boolean/)